# --skip-js-errors on specific test cases

Tags: javascript, debugging, testing, testcafe, browser-automation

I'm testing functionality that includes redirecting to an external page which I do not control. This page is throwing errors causing the test to fail.

Is there a way to ignore js errors for one specific test only? (I want errors on my site to cause a test fail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm happy to announce that [TestCafe of version 2.0](https://testcafe.io/404018/release-notes/framework/2022-8-31-testcafe-v2-0-0-released) and above provides a variety of options to skip JS errors on the testing pages conditionally at different levels (a whole test run, fixture, a whole test, etc.). To achieve this, you can use all TestCafe's interfaces CLI, a program API, and the config file.
Here is a small feature example for skipping errors with a specified message and page URL:

```js
fixture(**"My tests"**)
    .skipJsErrors({
        **message**: /Some expected message/ig
        **pageUrl**: /some-ads-site/
    });
```

Read more about this functionality in the [Docs](https://testcafe.io/documentation/404038/recipes/debugging/skip-javascript-errors).

Answer (score 7):

At present, TestCafe does not allow to do this. I've created a [proposal](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2775) in TestCafe repository for your use case. Track it to be aware about progress.

**UPDATE**:

There is an [example](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/tree/master/detached-examples/extended-error-tracking) that demonstrates how to extend the built-in error tracking functionality and skip JavaScript errors by a predicate function.